# Delphi XE 6 FMX TreeListVew text margin.left causes an runtime error

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I need to move TreeViewItem.Text on left. My code causes runtime error.

```
constructor TVppTreeViewItem.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
 var
 c:TTextControl;
begin
  inherited;
  self.Text:='test';
  self.TextObject.Align:=TAlignLayout.Left;
  self.TextObject.Margins.Left:=50;
end;
```

How do I code it correctly?

Comment: What error are you getting at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At creation time `TextObject` field of `TTreeItem` (and your `TVppTreeItem`) is `nil` and accessing it results in AV error. You should move code that modifies `TextObject` to `ApplyStyle` method where `TextObject` will be initialized from Style. Since it is not guaranteed that `TextObject` will be valid even after applying style, you should check it for `nil` before you attempt to do anything with it.

```
  TVppTreeViewItem = class(TTreeViewItem)
  protected
    procedure ApplyStyle; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

constructor TVppTreeViewItem.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  self.Text := 'test';
end;

procedure TVppTreeViewItem.ApplyStyle;
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(TextObject) then
    begin
      TextObject.Align := TAlignLayout.Left;
      TextObject.Margins.Left := 50;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Dalija Prasnikar.